# Is language detection of a string value possible in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto, language-detection

I have different VARCHAR values and would like to determine their language, for example:

"plutôt d'accord" --> FR

"Strongly Agree" --> EN

etc.

Is this possible in Presto SQL?